# it takes too long to connect to ssh server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, arch-linux

I've got two VMs with `arch linux` and `debian` (running under `virtual box`). Not long ago, it started to take a lot of time connecting to `arch` VM over `ssh`. The first time after a while, successive attempts happen quickly. Here's what I see in the `arch` VM:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user yuri service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.2.2.
# ^^^ spends a lot of time after this line
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 314
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for yuri
debug1: PAM: initializing for "yuri"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.0.2.2"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
Failed none for yuri from 10.0.2.2 port 35786 ssh2
```

`10.0.2.2` is the default gateway for the VMs. What does this all mean?

P.S. Here's a [good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94249/29867), thanks to which I was able to make some progress in researching the issue.

Comment: If the link is an acceptable and working answer, you should post it by the "Provide Your Own Answer" button. This helps mark the question as *answered* and makes it easier for others who view your question Title to see there is a working answer. Editing the question and adding the answer is okay, but it makes it harder for people to see that an Answer has been given.

Comment: @0xSheepdog, I believe the OP referred to the link mentioned and still not able to resolve the issue. That's why he has posted a question referring to that link in his question.

Comment: Thank you @Ramesh that point never occurred to me. Sorry x-yuri if I misunderstood you.

Comment: It sounds to me like "UseDNS no" on the server should avoid the delay.  (I often notice the delay when using ssh locally in the absence of working DNS).  Is that the case or not?

Comment: @0xSheepdog I added the link, because it helped me to find out more about the issue. But the issue is yet to be solved.

Comment: @sourcejedl I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I don't have `DNS` server installed on the host machine. Also, both VMs had `UseDNS = yes`, but it took too long to connect to only `arch linux` VM. Could you explain what `UseDNS` really means? I didn't get it from the `man` page. Preferably on the example of my setup.

Comment: @sourcejedi It seems you were right about "UseDNS no" solving the issue. Would you care answering this question? Details on what "UseDNS" has to do with this are appreciated.

Comment: [Here is an answer that addresses a possible cause for slow down.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318640/130579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is, that the problem are DNS requests timeouts. Try ... turning off the UseDNS option on the server you are connecting to.

The server log pretty much confirmed this (so well done for posting it :).

```
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.2.2.
# ^^^ spends a lot of time after this line
```

Looking at `man sshd_config`:

> ```
>  UseDNS  Specifies whether sshd(8) should look up the remote host name and
>          check that the resolved host name for the remote IP address maps
>          back to the very same IP address.  The default is “yes”.
> ```

Note that this is [pretty much pointless](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/64).  The check does *not* kill the connection.  If it doesn't pass, it just logs a finger-wagging message:

> Jul 9 05:43:00 brick sshd[18971]: Address 200.41.233.234 maps to host234.advance.com.ar, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

which only serves to generate scary false positives for users with incompetent ISPs.

OK, so how can this cause a delay?

If the DNS server doesn't respond immediately, the client will tend to wait & retry.  (In case a DNS packet was delayed or lost due to network congestion).  If the DNS server isn't responding at all, the client will eventually give up.  E.g. `dig` on my system retries for 15 seconds.  (It uses more specific dns library code, but the principle is the same).

```
$ time dig invalid @192.0.2.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> invalid @192.0.2.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

real    0m15.020s
user    0m0.010s
sys         0m0.011s
```

So the problem is the reverse lookup doesn't get a response.  You can run the same lookup on the server yourself manually, and you should see the same delay as ssh.  `getent hosts 10.0.2.2`.

Comment: Indeed, `getent hosts 10.0.2.2` and `dig -x 10.0.2.2` both take 5 second to execute and fail to make a reverse lookup. But I wanted to clarify about incompetent ISP or probably me. The difference between my VMs was that I specified a hostname for my host machine in `/etc/hosts` in `debian` VM, as opposed to `arch linux` VM. But I believe I did that just because I needed to access host machine once or more. So what is the proper `/etc/hosts` setup in the context of the issue? Do I possibly have to run DNS server locally?

Comment: Ok.  The hosts file is used for reverse lookups as well as normal lookups, so that probably is what causes the difference.  Are you saying the VMs are using an ISP DNS server, i.e. if you look `/etc/resolv.conf` it does _not_ show an IP address in one of your own network ranges like `10.0.2.2` ?  If so, then yes, it is ISP incompetence.  (And by implication they're unlikely to be competent to fix it on advice of a single consumer.  So you get to work around it yourself.  In which case, e.g. installing `unbound` as a recursive resolver on the host machine would be a good idea in general).

Comment: Ah, I missed two things.  1. the check SSH is running is not _expected_ to cause a delay even if the reverse mapping is missing.  The DNS should immediately return an empty answer, and the client would not retry the query.  Your problem isn't like the particular ISP incompetence I referred to in the answer, if that's what your phrasing meant.

Comment: 2. Note that `dig` does _not_ refer to `/etc/hosts`.  If `/etc/resolv.conf` lists the same nameserver on both VMs, I would expect `dig -x 10.0.2.2` to timeout on the debian VM as well.  And the same would apply to the host system i.e. the one VirtualBox is running on.

Comment: One suspicion is that VirtualBox almost certainly has an integrated DNS server, and it could be buggy somehow.  Another would be an old buggy DNS relay software (I've seen some badness on outdated DNSMasq) is running on your home router.

Comment: First, `resolv.conf` has `nameserver 10.0.2.3` on both VMs. Then, `dig -x 10.0.2.2` timeouts on both VMs, but not on host machine. Host machine has 'nameserver 127.0.1.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Host OS is `ubuntu`. As to incompetence, I didn't refer to anything in particular. I just would like to know who are to blame and which way things are supposed to be.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would also double-check one or two normal lookups on the VMs.  Since it works correctly on the host, I don't think it's a problem with your ISP (or your local router).  I'd say both your VMs are fine, it's VirtualBox that's broken (especially as they provide specific packages for each revision of  Ubuntu).  Whether that's a misconfiguration on your specific system, or a bug that needs fixing in VirtualBox?  I don't know, sorry.  Presumably there's a VirtualBox community forum you can sign up and get flamed at :-).

Comment: Surprisingly, `dig google.com` occasionally takes about 5 seconds to execute too. And now I understand why `ping` didn't show bad results (judging by time value), but it took quite a while for each line to appear. It must also has to do with `DNS`. So it must be either router or ISP...

Comment: Yep, that's right about `ping`.

Answer (score 2):

At this stage, there are many possibilities that might be causing a slow connection. From [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1294683.html) link, one issue that I see is related to encryption.

> Finally I know what is the issue.
>
> my /home/user dir is encrypted and therefore ssh wasn't able to access
>   it unless I am logged in.

Also one more possibility from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/321534/public-key-authentication-fails-only-when-sshd-is-daemon) is related to the `SELinux` service.

> Yes, `SELinux` is likely the cause. The `.ssh` dir is probably
>   mislabeled. Look at `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. It should be labeled
>   `ssh_home_t`. Check with `ls -laZ`. Run `restorecon -r -vv /root/.ssh`
>   if need be.

Also from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/how-to-speed-my-too-slow-ssh-login) link, I also see the PAM authentication might be a reason for slow SSH.

> Edit your "**/etc/ssh/ssh_config**" and comment out these lines:
>
> ```
> GSSAPIAuthentication yes
> GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention I checked my `GSSAPI*` settings. As to the first case, my home dir is not encrypted and server didn't refuse my key. And I don't have `/var/log/audit` directory on both host and guest machine. I'm now thinking if it's caused by `UseDNS = yes`, though it's that way on both VMs. And the one connecting too slowly is with `arch linux`. Reasoning on how exactly `UseDNS` affects the issue is appreciated.